# How do I disable Slack tab "badging" in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, notifications, slack

When I have unread slack messages, the Slack icon on the browser tab is a bright white (with a red dot when I get a mention):

[image]

When I have no unread messages, it is grey:

[image]

Is there anyway to disable this "badging" so the tab does not change at all, regardless of whether or not I have unread messages? I have Slack notifications disabled in Chrome, but this only affects the little notification pop-ups. I know that I can mute channels in Slack to not get any form of notification, but I just want to control of the tab behaves, because I would still like to see an indication in the Slack sidebar of which channels include unread messages when I visit the Slack tab itself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You aren't alone in this request, however it isn't possible at this time. The Slack Twitter account responded to this question only last month:

> Ah, it is unfortunately not possible to disable favicon auto update or mute direct messages.  Sorry to be the bearer of bad news.  - @SlackHQ

https://twitter.com/SlackHQ/status/1053219986741833728

Comment: Thanks for the info! That's unfortunate. I love it when software companies try to be cute when delivering bad news...

Answer (score 8):

You can use [Tab Modifier](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tab-modifier/hcbgadmbdkiilgpifjgcakjehmafcjai) to change the Icon to a permanent Icon that won't change when receiving messages. Just add the rule for your slack and change the icon, then refresh the slack page. Maybe a bit overkill of a solution, but it works.

Comment: I might actually give this a try! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for giving me my sanity back @Aree. I pointed Tab Modifier to this URL and it worked like a charm: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Slack_icon_2019.svg